# What would cause an custom element listing to just return everything?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I'm creating a plugin with its own ElementType, i've been using the [Events](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events) plugin by P&T for reference, so I thought everything was going fine.

Now when I go to my elements index, I seem to just get a listing for all elements, regardless of anything. What could cause this? I have my element type in my template like

```
{% set elementType = 'Custom_ElementType' %}
```

So if I change this to

```
{% set elementType = 'Entry' %}
```

I get a list of all entries with the correct sections and whatnot, which is what I expect, but when I change it to the former I get this:

[image]

I've obviously overlooked something but I can't figure it out, if anyone else has overcome something similar i'd be grateful for any pointers.

**Update**

Here is the code i'm using:

*Plugin_FooElementType.php*

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Plugin_FooElementType extends BaseElementType
{
  public function getName()
  {
    return Craft::t('Foo Element');
  }
  public function getSources($context = null)
  {
    $sources = array(
      '*' => array(
       'label' => Craft::t('All sources')
      )
    );
    return $sources;
  }

  public function populateElementModel($row)
  {
    return Plugin_FooModel::populateModel($row);
  }

  public function defineTableAttributes($source = null)
  {
    return array(
     'id' => Craft::t('ID'),
     'handle' => Craft::t('Handle'),
     'path' => Craft::t('Path'),
    );
  }
}
```

*_index.html*

```
{% extends "_layouts/elementindex" %}
{% set title = "Endpoints"|t %}

{% set elementType = 'Plugin_Foo' %}

{% set tabs = {
  events:    { label: "Events"|t, url: url('events') },
  requets: { label: "Requests"|t, url: url('plugin/foos') }
} %}
```

*Plugin_FooModel.php*

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Plugin_FooModel extends BaseElementModel
{
 protected $elementType = 'Plugin_Foo';


 protected function defineAttributes()
 {
    return array_merge(parent::defineAttributes(), array(
        'requestId' => AttributeType::Number,
        'handle' => AttributeType::Handle,
        'path' => AttributeType::String,
    ));
 }

 public function getCpEditUrl()
 {
    $relation = $this->getRelation();
    if ($relation)
    {
        return UrlHelper::getCpUrl('plugin/'.$relation->handle.'/'.$this->id);
    }
 }


 public function getRelation()
 {
    if ($this->relatedId)
    {
        return craft()->plugin->getRelationById($this->relatedId);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is likely just a typo in your template. Can you ensure that if your element type class name is of the format `Custom_PluginElementType` that your template code is then in the following format:

```
{% set elementType = 'Custom_Plugin' %}
```

Or if your element type class name is of the format `CustomElementType` that your template code is then in the following format:

```
{% set elementType = 'Custom' %}
```

Comment: Yeah as far as I can tell everything looks as though its correct, I have `PluginHandle_FooElementType` as the classname format which is referenced correctly in the templates (ended up copy and pasting it for sanity) and no dice. if I change `{% set elementType = 'Custom_Plugin' %}` to something random the admin page throws a 404, which makes me think it's referenced correctly.

Comment: so is your template code then
`{% set elementType = 'PluginHandle_Foo' %}`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've updated my question to give more details on what i've got set up :)

Comment: can you post your Plugin_FooModel code too?

Comment: Sure, sorry should have done that before!

Comment: I can't spot any issues with your code above. can you try reinstalling your plugin? and are you on Craft 2.5?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, yeah tried reinstalling multiple times and running the latest version of 2.5. I might try a clean craft install and go from there...thanks for your time though!

Comment: sure thing, be sure to let us know if you end up solving it!!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. You forgot to add the modifyElementsQuery method to your Plugin_FooElementType class:

```
public function modifyElementsQuery(DbCommand $query, ElementCriteriaModel $criteria)
{
    $query->join('plugin_foos plugin_foo', 'plugin_foo.id = elements.id');
}
```